# SQL percentage of unique rows by row value?

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I have ONE table (Transactions) with columns 'TransID','StoreName' and 'Amount'.
There are several stores listed with an Amount of '0'.

```
TRANSACTIONS
TransID   StoreName            Amount
1         Able Store             45
2         Baker Store            23
3         Charlie Store          9
4         Baker Store            0  
5         Charlie Store          0
6         Charlie Store          0
```

I need to generate a query to tell me for each distinct StoreName, 
What is the percentage of < $0.01 to > $0.01 for each store and output it.

In the above table, the result should look like this:

```
Able Store       100%
Baker Store      50%
Charlie Store    33%
```

I have tried COUNT, GROUP BY but I can't figure out how to do it...or if it is even possible...Or maybe i am just not that sharp...

Any suggestions are very welcome.  I still have a few hairs left to pull out....

What if i wanted to output the results on a monthly basis?
       STORE       MONTH1    MONTH2     MONTH3 ...
    Able Store       100%      50%
    Baker Store      50%        0%
    Charlie Store    33%       75%

Comment: AVG is a standard (aggregate) group function that may suit your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query works fine with not negative amount values.

```
select storename, round(avg(sign(amount)) * 100, 2) 
  from transactions group by storename;
```

If there can be negative amounts and you want to find the percentage of positive, use this query:

```
select storename, round(avg(case when amount > 0 then 1 else 0 end) * 100, 2) 
  from transactions group by storename;
```

If there can be negative amounts and you want to find the percentage of positive && negative, use this query:

```
select storename, round(avg(abs(sign(amount))) * 100, 2) 
  from transactions group by storename;
```

Comment: Nice solution, even if it is an abuse of the SIGN function. A negative amount (I know it does not make sense) would distort the result. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign)

Answer (score 1):

```
select storename, 
       sum(case when amount <> 0 then 1 end) * 100 / count(*) as percenate
from transactions
group by storename
```

Comment: so this will give me a percentage of amounts greater than 0 to amounts of 0?

Comment: @AaronBirnbaum It gives you the percentage of amounts not equal to zero to all amounts.

Comment: what if....I wanted to do this by months -( I have the dates in my table). wouuld i have to run the query by month, for each month?

Comment: @Aaron Birnbaum may add month column in the SELECT and GROUP BY parts: select storename, mon, sum(..) from transactions group by storename, mon